# Why shouldn't I use apt-get install --qq without a no-action modifier?

Tags: apt, software-installation, logging

From [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get.8):

> Note that quiet level 2 implies `-y`; you should never use `-qq` without a no-action modifier such as `-d`, `--print-uris` or `-s` as APT may decide to do something you did not expect.

Those options all, as suggested, don't actually install anything. What's wrong with using `-qq` as a quieter alternative to `-y` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `apt-get`  without a no-action modifier, it means you are going to perform some actual operation with packages like install, remove, upgrade etc.

Single `-q` means *quiet*. It produces output suitable for logging, omitting progress indicators. But when you use `-qq` which is quiet level 2, it  implies quit with `-y` (`--assume-yes`). In this case no output will be produces except error.

**Now why it is considered as dangerous?**

Sometime `apt-get` removes some packages to satisfy the dependency. Using `-qq` in such condition may remove some package which is important for you or for the system **without informing you**.

So it is not considered as safe because  such operation can make your system unstable.

Comment: Are there any other situations where it's a problem? That seems like a pretty obscure case - I don't recall ever seeing such a situation (or at least, being well enough informed that a message like that would have been at all useful).

Comment: @SteveBennett, [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man8/apt-get.8.html) of `apt-get` does not tell anything except ` APT may decided to do something you did not expect`. This is the one situation which came into my mind. I think, for an experienced  user it may not matter a lot , but for a new user it may be dangerous. I will do a bit more research on it and will update my answer if something comes across.